# 32 bit DLL loading 64 bit dependencies?

Tags: dll, 32bit-64bit

I've been having trouble loading this DLL, so I opened it up in Dependency Walker.

Despite being a 32 bit DLL, it seems to be trying to load 64 bit DLLs as dependencies, causing it to throw "Unable to load DLL" exceptions at runtime. Is there some way to specify which dependencies I'd like it to use?

(I'd post a screenshot of Dependency Walker, but I can't because I'm a new user).

Update:

One additional point. This DLL was working on the same computer with the same configuration, just a few days ago. However, I had to install a new hard drive as the previous one failed. After reinstalling all of the drivers, I'm left with this problem.

**Final update:**

Seems that it's a flawed installation. At some point the drivers were updated and they no longer install the 32 bit dependency DLLs on 64 bit systems.

Comment: Do you have 32bit versions as well?

Comment: @ChrisBint While most are there, it looks like a few of the 32 bit versions are missing. Seems the installer has been changed since I downloaded it last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has a [very specific search order to locate DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18(v=vs.100).aspx) which you can use to make it find the correct ones before the incorrect ones.

Comment: That makes sense. I wonder if the third party DLL I'm using doesn't use the GetSystemDirectory correctly.

Comment: @static416 I don't think the DLL is actually involved in finding its own dependencies (usually they are not). Where are the 64 bit libraries it finds located, and where are the 32-bit DLLs located?

Comment: After poking around a bit further, it's clear that there is something more significant going on. A few of the 32 bit versions of dependencies do not exist.

So either the previous installation was also missing 32 dependencies, yet somehow functioning. Or the driver installers have changed since the previous installation and they no longer install the 32 bit DLLs on 64bit systems.

Thanks for your help, I'll have to dig a little deeper on my side I think.